# How do I get data from Firebase and put it in this.props - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase

So, I have a Firebase setup and I'm trying to get my data from snapshot.val() into this.props.device, however 'this' is 'null' inside the this.firebaseRef.on() function. Any ideas?

```
var RegisteredDevice = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactFireMixin],

    componentWillMount: function() {
      this.firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://omniwolfdsn.firebaseio.com/Devices");

      this.firebaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        this.props.device = snapshot.val();
      });
    },

    propTypes: {

      name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      device: React.PropTypes.string,
      fire: React.PropTypes.string,
      noise: React.PropTypes.string,
      motion: React.PropTypes.string,
    }
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` as the 4th argument

```
  this.firebaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {

    this.props.device = snapshot.val();

  }, (error) => console.log( error ),  this);
```

According to the docs the signature of once is

```
on(eventType, successCallback, [failureCallback], [context] )
```

So the 4th argument can be `this`

Comment: @AndrewSteinheiser `this` can be the 4th argument.

Comment: I am not getting an error with that, however, this.props.device is undefined when I log it outside the function.

Comment: @AndrewSteinheiser are u using `getDefaultProps` ?

Comment: I am not, should I be?

Comment: I used getDefaultProps, and set device to 'default value', it does not change the value from 'default value'

Comment: @AndrewSteinheiser Normally, not, is not necessary. I cant see from your code why this.props is undefined.

Comment: @AndrewSteinheiser Are u sure that the `on` event is firing before you log the device property? You are attaching an async event, it will probably fire after your console.log outside of the function, so it is normal that this.props.device is undefined in that moment.